# Help me understand "LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a unit of work and a repository using EF 4 and POCOs.  Since EF requires an ordered set before it can Skip() and Take(), I added the following unit test (without mocks) just to pull out a record to see if it worked.

```
var myList = UOW.EntityRepo.Get( orderbyLambda: p => p.ID, page: 1, pageSize: 1);
```

This results in an expression of `orderbyLambda = {p => Convert(p.ID)}` and an error during enumeration.  The ID is a `tinyint` (Int16 / short)

So why does this fail to order by the ID?  More about the error

`Unable to cast the type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Object'.`

I define the orderbyLambda as `Expression<Func<E, object>> orderbyLambda`

EDIT:

The real killer is if I do this:

```
 orderbyLambda:  p => new { p.ID }
```

It works...  Why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is spotting "order by {object}" and panicking; it knows how to order by `string`, `int`, `short`, `DateTime`, etc - but `object` is a bit too vague.

You're going to need the actual lambda to be typed correctly; the simplest approach would be to make `Get` generic, i.e.

```
.... Get<TIdentity>(
         Expression<Func<E, TIdentity>> orderbyLambda, int page, int pageSize)
```

and then:

```
orderbyLambda: p => p.ID
```

should (without you changing the code at the caller) automatically make that a `Get<short>(...)` in this case via generic type inference. The other option is to leave it as `<E,object>`, but re-write the expression tree at the receiver. More work.

Comment: I had a similar problem trying to make OrderBy part of my repository API. LINQ to Entities balked at OrderBy(e => e.SomeCollection.Count). Changing the expression to OrderBy(e => new {e.SomeCollection.Count}) also worked for me.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the excellent explanation! It helped me to solve the problem. After understanding what's wrong, I've changed (Of Func(Of T, Object))) with (Of Func(Of T, String))) and the problem gone!